# How to keep the browser from requesting a file for a second time

Tags: http-headers, browser-cache, vs-web-site-project

I'm working on a web site, once finished the js files and pictures may remain unchanged for weeks, months or even years, who knows. So I though I could get a tremendous performance boost if I could instruct the browser to download and forget, that is: if the file is already on the local cache, retrieve and use that version regardless anything else, so the only way a file would be downloaded twice would be if the user clears the browser's cache. This obviously implies a commitment, because if something in my web site changes, I would be forced to change the name of the affected file(s) too, but with the huge advantage of being capable of overriding the browser's local cache whenever I need or want, gaining full control of it, fast, simple and wasting zero band width and CPU cycles.

I'm trying to achieve this by adding the proper cache commands to the HTTP response header. 
Here is a sample:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: Keep-Alive
Date: Sat, 27 Jul 2013 02:24:05 GMT
Content-Type: application/x-javascript
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 13728
Last-Modified: Sat, 27 Jul 2013 00:37:59 GMT
ETag: "20130726193759"
Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 2014 05:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: public, max-age=31536000
```

As you may realize, I'm instructing the browser to keep the file on its cache one full year. But I don't know if I'm doing something wrong, because the desktop browsers still make the file request with the **If-None-Match** parameter, in this case I just tell them the file hasn't changed which is sub optimal, but the case of the Android's browser is even worst, because it makes the request as if it was the first time.

Can anyone tell me if I'm doing something wrong???

Answer (score 1):

You need to turn on the browser leverage caching using [`.htaccess`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html) files.

In order to make the files cached by the browser, say for example the images, stylesheets, JavaScript etc, you need to turn on the Leverage Caching using a `.htaccess` file, by which you can specifically inform the browser that specific content won't be changing for a specified period - a week/month/year. As the browser will not repeatedly request that content it will drastically improve your page loading speed for future visits from the same browser.

In your `.htaccess` file, you can add the following (for files that won't change)

```
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 days"
```

So this way you can send the HTTP headers to set the expiry dates of different files.

You can refer an article [here](http://fortheloveofseo.com/blog/performance/leverage-browser-caching-how-to-add-expires-headers/) which will teach you in detail about the leverage caching and how to turn it on.

Comment: If you explain step by step _how_ to do that I might just upvote this answer.

Comment: @Floris I will update thin in 10 mins, sorry I was on mobile and I am finding difficult to add the code here.

Comment: The link you gave counts as "how to do that"!

Comment: @Floris Explained it :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it is specific for websites hosted with the Apache web server, which is not my case. I need to do the job with HTTP response headers only since I am using my own home brewed web server.